# How do convert Java DropTarget to TransferHandler code

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have this code to allow user to drop an image onto a dropzone label and then display it in anpther label *artworkLabel*. However it seems I should no longer be using `DropTarget` but `TransferHandler` , is that correct.  How would I convert to use `TransferHandler` instead

Dialog invokes `DropTarget` with

```
JLabel dropzone        = getNewDropzone();
new ArtworkDropTarget(dropzone, newArtwork);
```

And `ArtworkDropTarget` subclasses `Droptarget`

```
package com.jthink.songkong.ui.startdialog.editsongs;

import com.jthink.songkong.ui.MainWindow;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import static com.jthink.songkong.ui.startdialog.editsongs.ArtworkTab.ARTWORK_SIZE;

public class ArtworkDropTarget extends DropTarget
{
   private JLabel displayArtwork;

    public static DataFlavor uriListFlavor;     //This is used by Linux for loading files
    public static DataFlavor imageFlavor;       //This is used by Firefox, when drag single image file
    public static DataFlavor imageUrlFlavor;    //This is used by Firefox, when drag single image file
    public static DataFlavor pictImageFlavor;   //This is used by OSX for iTunes
    static
    {
        try
        {
            uriListFlavor   = new DataFlavor("text/uri-list;class=java.lang.String");
            imageUrlFlavor  = new DataFlavor("application/x-java-url;class=java.net.URL");
            imageFlavor = new DataFlavor("image/x-java-image;class=java.awt.Image");
            pictImageFlavor = new DataFlavor("image/x-pict;class=java.io.InputStream");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cne)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to create uri-list flavor in drop target:" + cne.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ArtworkDropTarget(Component c, JLabel displayArtwork)
            throws HeadlessException
    {
        super(c, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY, null, true, null);
        this.displayArtwork= displayArtwork;
    }

    /**
     * When used as Drop target
     *
     * @param dtde
     */
    public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde)
    {
        dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
        Transferable trans = dtde.getTransferable();
        try
        {
            if (trans.isDataFlavorSupported(imageFlavor))
            {
                MainWindow.logger.severe("Received Image"+trans.getTransferData(ArtworkDropTarget.imageFlavor));
                setExistingArtwork((Image)trans.getTransferData(ArtworkDropTarget.imageFlavor));
            }
            else if (trans.isDataFlavorSupported(imageUrlFlavor))
            {
                MainWindow.logger.severe("Received ImageUrl"+trans.getTransferData(ArtworkDropTarget.imageUrlFlavor));
                setExistingArtwork((URL) trans.getTransferData(ArtworkDropTarget.imageUrlFlavor));
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow.logger.severe("Unknown DataFlavor for ImageUrl");
            }
            dtde.dropComplete(true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            dtde.dropComplete(false);
        }
    }

    private void setExistingArtwork(Image image)
    {
        //try
        //{
            BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(ARTWORK_SIZE, ARTWORK_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            ret.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, ARTWORK_SIZE, ARTWORK_SIZE, null);
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ret);
            displayArtwork.setIcon(ii);
            //displayArtwork.setText(image.getWidth() + " x " + image.getHeight());
        //}
        //catch (IOException ex)
        //{
        //    MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        //}
    }

    private void setExistingArtwork(URL imageUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(ARTWORK_SIZE, ARTWORK_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            ret.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, ARTWORK_SIZE, ARTWORK_SIZE, null);
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ret);
            displayArtwork.setIcon(ii);
            displayArtwork.setText(image.getWidth() + " x " + image.getHeight());
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody will do your job here especially when we must do a reverse engeneering of your requirements before. But you can find a good example about D&D of images [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DragandDropSupportforImages.htm).

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html) and [the tutorial to which it links](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html)?

Comment: @VGR yes, but the tutorial discusses in inbuilt support but only seems to exist for textual data, and I found the hole tutorial confusing and  I couldn't relate it to my requirements